# Sharepoint 2010 Survey - Create questions from a list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, survey

I have a list of reports in our business and what i want to do is send out a survey to every user asking them a set of questions per report.  For each report we want to ask the following questions:

Do you use the report?  Y/N
How often do you use it?  Daily/Weekly/Monthly/Quarterly/Annually
Is this report sent out externally?  Y/N

So do you think this is possible using a Sharepoint Survey?  A point in the right direction would be good.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a long investigation i concluded that SharePoint was not the solution i required and instead used SurveyMonkey which covered my requirement perfectly.